# Using whiptail with variable containing dash ('-')

Tags: bash, whiptail

I want to display a menu in linux bash using `whiptail`
When a menu item contains one or more dashes, whiptail fails to show the menu.
Example with only one item:

```
MQTT_PublisherArgs='-h {host} -t {topic} -m "{{message}}"'
whiptail --title "MQTT Configuration" --menu "" 0 70 0 "Publisher Arguments" "$MQTT_PublisherArgs"
```

When I replace the dashes with another character e.g. underscore, the menu is shown correctly.
I tried to escape the dashes with `\-` but the backslash is shown in the menu.

How can I display the menu item `-h {host} -t {topic} -m "{{message}}"`

When the user selects this item he will prompted to enter his proper arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
"$MQTT_PublisherArgs"
```

with

```
-- "$MQTT_PublisherArgs"
```

to tell `whiptail` that the following are not options.

From `man whiptail`:

> whiptail  interprets  arguments  starting with a dash "-" as being arguments.  To avoid this,
>          and start some text in, for example, a menubox item, with a dash, whiptail honours the getopt
>          convention  of  accepting  the special argument "--" which means that all following arguments
>          with dashes are to be treated verbatim and not parsed as options.

Comment: As I read it, doesn't the OP have *several different* arguments in that string variable? As such, I'm not confident that the Right Thing is anything short of replacing it with an array.